# Cannot map a texture to the object

Tags: opengl-es

hi am new to opengles and recently i started working with textures and now am facing a small problem with it.that is am not able to map the textures to the objects,to be clear am using a png file and creating a texture with it.till here everything goes fine but i dono what's the problem in texture mapping,only few files with .png formats are working fine and i can see them perfectly mapped onto the objects and when i use my own images which are of the same ".png" formats am unable to get the desired one... plz help me to fix this issue.thx in adv.

Comment: Please provide some more details on your problem. With this information it is almost impossible to pinpoint your problem. Maybe your pngs are larger and thus hit the maximum texture size for ogles?

Comment: thanks for the hint and am so sorry i couldnot address you coz i dono your name really thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi finally i found the solution for the issue i faced,it was regarding the pixel size.the pixel size of the image was not a power of 2.so i edited the pixel size of the images that i was using and it started working.....